# Name/Value pair with no name

Tags: api, json, apexrest

I have a JSON response that gives me an array as part of the response, the array only ever seems to hold one value but with no name. I don't know how to parse the response.

```
  "state": [
"scheduled"
```

],

I have created a response object that has a list called state and a class called state but i don't know what variable to put in the state class to accept the value. Even if I leave the class blank I still get an error. Has anyone dealt with anything like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a List of String, like this:

```
public class Response {
    // other values may be here
    public List<String> state;
    // And others after
}
```

You can take your JSON and put it into [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com) and it will give you a class in Apex you can use for parsing.